# Im trying to build a e-commerce store and am having troubles adding to cart with python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a e-commerce flask site and i am stuck on adding to cart secquence.

I  have tryed to use a POST request to store it in a db then display it in a /cart view. Any help would be great thanks so much. Heres what i got so far.

```
models.py
class ATC(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(80)) 
description = db.Column(db.Text)
price = db.Column(db.String(80))


views.py

def shop():
products = Product.query.all()
return render_template('product/index.html', prod=products)


@app.route('/addcart', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def addcart():

title = request.form['{{ product.title }}']
description = request.form['{{ product.description|safe }}']
price = request.form['{{ product.price }}']

add = ATC(title=title, description=description, price=price)  

db.session.add(add) 
db.session.commit()


return redirect(url_for('cart'))



index.html (for the shop)
{% if current_user.has_role('admin') %}
<a href="{{ url_for('new_product') }}" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"> New Product</i></a>
{% endif %}
<div class="row text-center">
{% for product in prod %}

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <form name="addForm" id="addForm" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('addcart') }}" novalidate>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <li class="header"><img src="{{ product.images }}" width="180" height="175"></li>
          <p class="card-text1">--------------------------------------</p>
          <h4 class="card-title" name="{{ product.title }}">{{ product.title }}</h4>
          <p class="card-text" name="{{ product.description|safe }}">{{ product.description|safe }}</p>
        </div>
          <h4 class="card-title" name="{ product.price }}">${{ product.price }}</h4>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">ATC</button>
              {% if current_user.has_role('admin') %}
              <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top:5px;">
              <a href="{{ url_for('delete_product', product_id=product.id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete!</a>
              <a href="{{ url_for('edit_product', product_id=product.id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit!</a>
              </div>
              {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>

   {% endfor %}
```

I want be able to store this info into a db and the display it the the /cart view.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: hi, I am wondering on how to add a product to cart from index using the /addcart view to display it then in the /cart view